# call of overloaded ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ with suffices for pairs is ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, c++17

I cannot compile the following code.

```
void print_number(long n) {
   std::cout << n << std::endl;
}

void print_number(float n) {
   std::cout << n << std::endl;
}

void print_pair(std::pair<std::string, long> p) {
   std::cout << std::get<1>(p) << std::endl;
}

void print_pair(std::pair<std::string, float> p) {
   std::cout << std::get<1>(p) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   print_number(12l);
   print_number(3.4f);

   print_pair({"long", 12l});
   print_pair({"float", 3.4f});

   return 0;
}
```

`print_number` functions work well. However, compiler complains about the overloaded `print_pair` functions:
`error: call of overloaded ‘print_pair(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous`.

Are suffices in `<brace-enclosed initializer list>` or `std::pair` not working? How can I overload functions receiving a `std::pair` parameter?

Comment: You can tell the compiler what overload to use by providing an explicit constructor.

Comment: @OutOfBound How can I? Would you please give me an example?

Answer (score 3):

Tl;dr

In order to solve the ambiguity, you can provide the correct type to the compiler:

```
print_pair(std::make_pair<std::string, long>("long", 12l));
print_pair(std::make_pair<std::string, float>("float", 3.4f));
```

or

```
print_pair(std::make_pair(std::string("long"), 12l));
print_pair(std::make_pair(std::string("float"), 3.4f));
```

---

The ambiguity problem arises from the fact `"long"` and `"float"` are not `std::string`, but rather `const char[]`.

So when you try to construct a `std::pair` using the following expression: `std::pair{"long", 12l}`, what you obtain is a `std::pair<const char[5], long>`.

(The same for the float; i.e., `std::pair<const char[5], float>`).

Your overload `print_pair` accepts `std::pair<std::string, long>` or `std::pair<std::string, float>`. None of the previous types match, so the compiler has to perform a conversion. Because of that, it cannot automatically deduct what conversion you want to perform. Both are valid.

For example:

```
                    std::pair<const char[5], long>  
                                  |
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
  v                                                              v
std::pair<std::string, long>                          std::pair<std::string, float>
```

To "prove" the problem is the `std::string` (neither `long` or `float`), you can also solve the ambiguity constructing a proper `std::string` (instead of an array of `char`):

```
print_pair(std::make_pair(std::string("long"), 12l));
print_pair(std::make_pair(std::string("float"), 3.4f));
```

Starting from *C++17*, this boilerplate can be simplified with:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

print_pair(std::pair{"long"s, 12l});
print_pair(std::pair{"float"s, 3.4f});
```

Comment: CTAD is introduced in C++17, not C++14.

Comment: @Stu Just noticed your code uses `std::tuple`. OP is `std::pair` as my answer

Comment: @Biagio Festa Ooops. That would be my messing around to see if I could make it work... Yes, once restored to `std::pair` your version works. Guess I'm taking "A pair is a specific case of a std::tuple with two elements." too literally...

Comment: `std::make_pair(std::string("long"), 12l)` or `std::pair<std::string, long>("long", 12l)` (or simply `std::pair{"long"s, 12l}` in C++17). we should let compiler deduce parameter for `std::make_pair`.

Comment: Sure, they work, as if `print_number`... I changed `std::string` to `const char*` from `print_pair`, however, it still complains ambiguity... Isn't there any workaround to use only brace-enclosed initializer list?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi starting from C++17 you can use *CTAD* and `std::string_literals`. It's what I reported in the last snippet code in my answer. You cannot avoid `std::pair` tho.

Comment: With `g++-8.3`, it says `error: missing template arguments before ‘{’ token`...

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi you probably want to enable *C++17*. With *gcc* you have to add `-std=c++17` option

Comment: Oh, it works. But I still should provide `std::pair`. Do you have any idea to call a function using only `<brace-enclosed initializer list>`?

Comment: "The ambiguity problem arises from the fact "long" and "float" are not std::string, but rather const char[]." Uh, no. If you made them actually strings, you'd find this was still ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

With `print_pair({"long", 12l});`, there are 2 possible overloads:

- `void print_pair(std::pair<std::string, long>)`
- `void print_pair(std::pair<std::string, float>)`

`{"long", 12l}` has no types, but is valid initialization for both `std::pair<std::string, long>` and `std::pair<std::string, long>`.

So the call is ambiguous.

`print_pair(std::pair{"long", 12l});` would also be ambiguous
as `std::pair<const char*, long>` can equally be converted to `std::pair<std::string, long>` and `std::pair<std::string, long>`.

You have to call it:

- `print_pair(std::pair{std::string("long"), 12l});` to have exact match.

Comment: Can I check the type of the second element of a pair later?

Comment: Unsure what you mean.. `template <typename T1, typename T2> void print_pair(const std::pair<T1, T2>& p) {
   std::cout << std::get<1>(p) << std::endl; /*or print_number(std::get<1>(p))*/
}` ?

Comment: What should I do call the function like `print_pair({"long", 12l});`...? Is it still possible?

Comment: If there are overloads (or template), I don't see way to call it with `print_pair({"long", 12l});`

Answer (score 2):

C++'s overload resolution logic doesn't consider piece-wise conversions, it only considers the *whole* conversion for a given parameter/argument pair.

With this call:

```
print_pair({"long", 12l});
```

We have two viable candidates. One candidate takes a `std::pair<std::string, long>` and the other takes a `std::pair<std::string, float>`.

What C++ doesn't do (and what you might be thinking it does) is consider these parts separately - and say that well, `"long"` to `std::string` is the same in both cases but `12l` to `long` is better than `12l` to `float`, as a result the conversion to `pair<string, long>` wins. This *would* be how it would work if instead of having two functions that take `pair`s, we had two functions that took two arguments:

```
print_two("long", 12l); // calls print_two(string, long)
```

But C++ doesn't work like that. What it does do is consider these parts together. That *braced-init-list* can be used to construct both `std::pair` specializations. Both are viable. Both are user-defined conversions. Neither is better than the other, hence ambiguous. We really have no mechanism in the language to make this kind of piecewise conversion work.

You have to either just say what you mean:

```
print_pair(std::pair<std::string, long>("long", 12l));
```

Or take two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers. I up-voted all of them, however, what I wanted to do was call the function `print_pair` with heterogeneous `<brace-enclosed initializer list>`s.

What I finally did is:

```
struct number {
    number(long n) {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
    number(float n) {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
};

void print_pair(std::pair<std::string, number> p) {}
```

In this way, the following function calls can be compiled without the `error: call of overloaded ‘print_pair(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous`.

```
print_pair({"long", 12l});
print_pair({"float", 3.4f});
```

Note that, using two `struct`s whose constructors take `long` and `float` respectively, we will go back to the same problem of ambiguity.